# Does What I have ploted for Normal distribution or for my PDFcode?

Tags: distributions, histograms

Really , am confused and mixed in the same time , I have tried to plot the Histogram of my PDF which it is already integrated to 1 (Normalised) , I didn't succeed to compute anything related to that PDF only Moment the response of wolfram cloud was "pdfF[#1][z] is not regognized by the system"   , Now I have added this commond to generate my Histogram Plot :`pdfF[#1][z]=NormalDistribution[]`

From the latter commond i become able to do all thing related to my PDF distribution, For example  I have plot my Histogram with Normal Distribution Histogram in unified Graph as shown below  using thr following Code:

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500];
data2 = RandomVariate[pdfF[#1][z], 500];
Histogram[{data1, data2}]
```

Now My question here After seen the below Plot , Does what I have did for My PDF or for Normal Distribution ? Or what operation I did ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Your "PDF" definition is neither a [`PDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html) nor a proper syntax for a function definition.

```
pdfF[#1][z] = NormalDistribution[]

(* NormalDistribution[0, 1] *)
```

Irrespective of the syntax error, your subsequent call returns a distribution, i.e., `NormalDistribution[0, 1]`.

Your `data1` and `data2` are defined with the same distribution. Their values differ only because they each start with different random seeds. Resetting the random seed  with [`SeedRandom`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeedRandom.html) would produce **identical** results.

```
SeedRandom[1234];
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500];
SeedRandom[1234];
data2 = RandomVariate[pdfF[#1][z], 500];

data1 === data2

(* True *)
```

The proper way to define a `PDF` and keep clear the difference between a distribution and a `PDF`

```
dist = NormalDistribution[0, 1];

pdf[z_] = PDF[dist, z]

(* E^(-(z^2/2))/Sqrt[2 π] *)
```

Or if you want a pure function

```
pdf2 = PDF[dist, #] &

(* PDF[dist, #1] & *)
```

Note that `dist` did not evaluate since [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) has the attribute [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html)

```
Attributes[Function]

(* {HoldAll, Protected} *)
```

Both `pdf` and `pdf2` give the same result

```
pdf[z] == pdf2[z]

(* True *)
```